# Introduction to Real Analysis Problem

Tags: real-analysis

Show that, given any element $x$  of the set $(0,∞)$, there is another element $y∈(0,∞)$ with the property that $y< x$. Deduce that $(0,∞)$ has no minimum.

Comment: So, what are your thoughts?

Comment: @measure2012 where are you encountering a problem

Comment: My friend asked me about this question...Probably is the exercise from reference book

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{2}<1$.

Comment: @measure2012 I can't understand if you are ironic. In this case you shouldn't, because I essentially gave you the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick $x>0$, and set $y=\frac{x}{2}$. Then $y>0$ and $y<x$, since
$$
x-y=x-\frac{x}{2}=\frac{x}{2}>0.
$$
In other words, there are arbitrarily small positive numbers, while the minimum of $(0,+\infty)$ should be the smallest positive number. Therefore such a minimum does not exist.